# XML on eXist-db : err:XPST0003 unexpected token

Tags: xml, xslt, xforms, exist-db, xsltforms

I have an XML document on eXist-db but the compiler is complaining giving me the following error:

> Cannot compile xquery: exerr:ERROR org.exist.xquery.XPathException:
>   err:XPST0003 unexpected token: xml-stylesheet
>   href="../xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl" [at line 2, column
>   1]

I have tried everything I could think of:

- copying the xml on to an xhtml document.
- removing the tags that it's complaining about ( but it then goes to complain about other tags)
- run the xml in eXist with no result
- run the html generated by it in the browser with another error too.

This is the relevant part of the XML I think:

nuevacontribucion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?><?css-conversion no?><?xsltforms-options debug="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
<head>
    <title>Crear una nueva Contribución</title>
    <link href="../css/loading.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="vendors/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <script src="vendors/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"/>
    <style>
        input[type='text'], select{
            min-height: 30px;
        }
        iframe{
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 200px !important;
        }
        .datepicker .aid-button{
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
```

If I remove the xml-stylesheet tag then it throws the same exception but complaining about css-conversion, if I remove it then it's about the following tag, if I remove it then it's about xmlns not being defined or something.

Comment: It's treating your XML file as an XQuery; what are you doing to the file when the error is thrown? What does "run the XML" mean?

Comment: How did you store the XML document into the database? The error you are getting is from the execution of an XQuery, which is not related to the problem you describe.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703669/unexpected-xml-token-in-exist-db-when-they-are-correct Which I already commented on yet @dylan-valez did not respond, so if he is waiting a week, it seems to be not on us?

Comment: 1) i'm not doing anything to the file when the error is thrown, by saying run the XML i mean hitting the run button in exist-db to see the direct output as i've done with other xml files.

2) the file was stored with the java admin client, i restored a backup and it stored files and folders as it was in the backup.

3) i responded but never got an answer back, i really need this so yeah i made another question, sorry.

Comment: Have you already changed the XSLT processor to Xalan instead of Saxon ?

Comment: i have not done that, care to explain how should i do that and why it would matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the XSLT engine from Saxon to Xalan.

By default, eXist-db 2.0 comes with the following configuration in  `conf.xml` in the eXist-db install directory:

```
 <transformer class="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl">
```

To solve your problem, change it to:

```
<transformer class="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl">
```